# PyQt 5 : How to save contents of the line edit into a txt file ? How to load the contents of a text file, to autofill the line edit?

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am trying to create a configuration tool that helps link attributes of one tool with another. I have created the config window using PyQt5. 
I want to:

1. Save the value of the line edit, into a text file. ---> when clicked on Save
2. Load the values of a text file , into the line edit ---> when clicked on Load

This is how the UI looks

The UI of the config file- Config.ui

[image]

I have tried the functions getSaveFileName , getOpenFileName but all i get is the path on the cmd, and no actual file is saved or opened.

what should be done in order to save the file contents ?

Please be kind with your answers :)

This is how the programming GUI looks like :

```
# Config program using PyQt5

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog
form_class = uic.loadUiType("Config.ui")[0]  # Load the UI


class Mapper(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self,  parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        # Bind the event handlers to the buttons
        self.saveButton.clicked.connect(self.saveFileDialog)
        self.loadButton.clicked.connect(self.loadFileDialog)

    def saveFileDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()",  "",
                                                  "All Files (*);;Text Files (*.txt)", options=options)
        if fileName:
            print(fileName)

    def loadFileDialog(self):
        options = QFileDialog.Options()
        options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
        files, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames()", "",
                                                "All Files (*);;Python Files (*.py)", options=options)
        if files:
            print(files)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
myWindow = Mapper()
myWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

This is how the Config.ui looks :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>545</width>
    <height>728</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Ignored" vsizetype="Ignored">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="focusPolicy">
   <enum>Qt::NoFocus</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Configuration Window</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QFrame" name="mainFrame">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>-10</y>
      <width>911</width>
      <height>721</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShape">
     <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
    </property>
    <property name="frameShadow">
     <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
    </property>
    <widget class="QGroupBox" name="mapGroupBox">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>481</width>
       <height>581</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="title">
      <string>MAPPING ATTRIBUTES</string>
     </property>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="ecuGroupBox">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>20</x>
        <y>30</y>
        <width>211</width>
        <height>531</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="title">
       <string>ECU TEST Attributes</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="ModuleName">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>30</y>
         <width>111</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ModuleName</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="aObjectType">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>60</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>aObjectType</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="TestDescription">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>90</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TestDescription</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Preconditions">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>390</y>
         <width>91</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Preconditions</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Testcase_ID">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>210</y>
         <width>91</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Testcase_ID</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="function">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>330</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Function</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Priority">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>300</y>
         <width>55</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Priority</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="TestName">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>240</y>
         <width>71</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TestName</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="TestFocus">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>150</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TestFocus</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Action">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>420</y>
         <width>61</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Action</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="CreatedBy">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>480</y>
         <width>81</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>CreatedBy</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="TestLocation">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>360</y>
         <width>101</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TestLocation</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Status">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>270</y>
         <width>55</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Status</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Req_ID">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>180</y>
         <width>55</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Req_ID</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="TestPictureName">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>120</y>
         <width>111</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>TestPictureName</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="ExpectedResult">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>450</y>
         <width>111</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Nirmala UI</family>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>ExpectedResult</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="doorsGroupBox">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>250</x>
        <y>29</y>
        <width>211</width>
        <height>531</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="title">
       <string>DOORS Attributes</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>30</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>60</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>90</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_4">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>120</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_5">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>150</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_6">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>180</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_7">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>210</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_8">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>240</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_9">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>270</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_10">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>300</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_11">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>330</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_12">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>360</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_13">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>390</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_14">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>420</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_15">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>450</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_16">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>480</y>
         <width>181</width>
         <height>22</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="saveButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>30</x>
       <y>630</y>
       <width>93</width>
       <height>28</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="toolTip">
      <string>Save The Current Configuration</string>
     </property>
     <property name="toolTipDuration">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Save</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>140</x>
       <y>630</y>
       <width>93</width>
       <height>28</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="toolTip">
      <string>Load Existing Configuration</string>
     </property>
     <property name="toolTipDuration">
      <number>1</number>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Load</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>545</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: show Mapping.ui please

Comment: I have added the Mapping.ui code in the edit :)

Comment: I have changed the whole logic of my program, I think it is really simple now, Just saving and retrieving the contents of the form. :)